# How to make GetStream post activities of Facebook page

Tags: django, facebook-page, getstream-io

I would like to use GetStream to create customizable Facebook Page Plugin to display all the recent activities on the website (same as this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

However, I have no idea how to connect GetStream with particular Facebook page.

#### Question:

How do I get ID of a page and where do I put it inside the code so it pulls all the recent activities and post them on he website?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that we, as Stream, can automate. Stream's APIs don't scrape data, we expect that you'll write code that scrapes the data, and sends it to our API to retrieve later.